# Ngrx Effects withLatestFrom causes an exception

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I am trying to dispatch an action that will load books depending on selected publisher.

Here is the sample of the effect class:

```
@Injectable()
export class LibraryEffects {
    @Effect({})
    bookRequest = this.actions.pipe(
        ofType(BOOK_LIST_REQUEST),
        withLatestFrom(
            this.store.pipe(
                select(selectBookshop),
                map(bookshop => bookshop.library.publisher),
            )
        ),
        map(([action, publisher]) => {
            window.console.log(action, publisher);
            return new BookRequestSuccess();
        })
    );

    constructor(
        private actions: Actions,
        private store: Store<AppState>
    ) {}
}
```

When application starts storage does not contain nor 'bookshop' neither 'library' properties in it which are getting filled later with user actions. After that user triggers 'BOOK_LIST_REQUEST' action and should retrieve appropriate list of books.

But an exception occurs as soon as effect is registered even without calling 'BOOK_LIST_REQUEST' action that should subscribe to 'library' property in storage:

```
core.js:15714 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'library' of null
```

This seems weird as if effect is registering an observable to the storage on effect registration in module and not on calling 'BOOK_LIST_REQUEST' action.

What could be an issue here ? Am i doing reading from storage in this effect somehow wrong?

Comment: Looks like `AppState` is not initialized with the default state. Please share your `AppState` and reducer and selector code.

Comment: It is initialized with default state as it should be. Simply default state does not contain those properties. Problem is with subscription to those properties that happens upon registration of an effect instead of action dispatch.

Comment: Then make sure to return the initial state from reducer in default `switch case`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this issue is fixed if withLatestFrom is wrapped in concatMap operator as it is done in [ngrx documentation example](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects#incorporating-state) (collection.effects.ts).

```
        ofType(BOOK_LIST_REQUEST),
        concatMap(action => of(action).pipe(
          withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(
            select(selectBookshop), 
            map(bookshop => bookshop.library.publisher)
         )
       )
```